# Linking HTML elements position to images

Tags: html, css

I would like to make HTML elements position "fixed" on background images.

**Example**
I want to create a PHP/SQL strategy/management game where the user interface is a cockpit, a rocket cockpit (because the game takes place in space). So the backgroud image would be something like :

- Buttons on the left to control the destination of the rocket
- Buttons on the right to controle what actions the player can do
- And the windscreen in the middle where most HTML displays

I want HTML elements (mostly divs) to be placed exactly where they should be (the div displaying the speed of the rocket must be exactly under the speedometer drawn at the bottom of my picture).

The problem is that, no matter if I use `top: 300px;` or `top: 15%;`, when the screen is been resized, every elements move out of their original place, which screws up everthing.

**What do you guys think ?**

**NB :** the background picture needs to be responsive, let's say here that it always fills the viewport

Comment: I think that you need to show your codes so that we have a working example

Comment: Fixed is relative to the viewport. You need to fix the main container, then set the embedded elements relative to that. Can you post your code?

Comment: I dont have any examples yet, but it is clear in my mind. Let's say that you have a picture of a speedometer at the bottom of the screen. What do I have to do so my HTML div containing the value of the speed always stays inside the speedometer, no matter the size of the window?

Answer (score 0):

The element position 'Fixed' will relative to the browser window.

You may want to use position 'absolute' and 'relative'.

For example :

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 530px;
  height: 207px;
}
.score {
  position: absolute;
  top: 8px;
  right: 0px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 35px;
}
.btn-1 {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 10px;
  left: 10px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 35px;
  background-color: red;
}
.btn-2 {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 10px;
  left: 70px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 35px;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img src="https://opengameart.org/sites/default/files/background0.png" width="530" height="207">
  <div class="score">Score : 1,200</div>
  <div class="btn-1"></div>
  <div class="btn-2"></div>
</div>
```

You should give size of element (width, height) for position 'absolute'

Ref : https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_position.asp

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But this is not responsive : your container keeps the same size no matter how much I resize the window. I guess I should have added in my question that I want my background picture to fill the viewport... But still I thank you for your time HeeMZa :)

Comment: You may change pixel (px) to percent (%) for position or size

Comment: As i mentionned in my first post, I already try switching from (px) to (%), but the image and the html elements dont move the same way when I resize the window.